# Combine text from multiple cells into a single cell on other Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need help, I want to combine multiple cells in one other cell in another sheet.
I have 4 Collums in my first **Sheet1**, filed with data:

1. Id's (A1:A)
2. Dates(B1:B)
3. Name(C1:C)
4. Comments(D1:D)

And on my other **Sheet2**, I can select Id's(G3) from a dropdown and get more data from other sheets.
Now I want to Combine all Dates, Name and Comment in one cell on my **Sheet2**.
I want something like, I pick an Id on **Sheet2** and get every Comment with name and Date from **Sheet1** in one cell.
I want it like

```
1.1.2018 peter Comment  
2.1.2018 hans Comment  
15.1.2018 peter Comment...
```

The cell can expand I only need everything in one cell.
Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need it everything in one cell, try this:

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10); FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!B1:B &" "&
                                    Sheet1!C1:C &" "&
                                    Sheet1!D1:D); Sheet1!A1:A=G3))
```

[image]
[image]

---

---

**blank error fix:**

```
=IF(G3<>""; JOIN(CHAR(10); FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!B1:B &" "&
                                               Sheet1!C1:C &" "&
                                               Sheet1!D1:D); Sheet1!A1:A=G3));)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now another question how can I insert a line break or an empty line after every line?

Comment: @Vic add one more `CHAR(10)`

Comment: @Vic `=JOIN(CHAR(10); FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!B1:B &" "&
                                    Sheet1!C1:C &" "&
                                    Sheet1!D1:D&CHAR(10)); Sheet1!A1:A=G3))`

Answer (score 0):

you need this in **Sheet2!H3**:

**`=FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!B1:B&" "&Sheet1!C1:C&" "&Sheet1!D1:D); Sheet1!A1:A=G3)`**

[image]
[image]

---

---

**#N/A fix:**

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!B1:B&" "&Sheet1!C1:C&" "&Sheet1!D1:D);Sheet1!A1:A=G3);)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a drop down this should work

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", True,QUERY(A:D, "Select * Where A = '"&E2&"' ",0))
```

you will need to change your query to match ur data. share a copy of ur sheet if u can.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5oBL.png this won't do as OP requested to be formatted

Comment: Yes, you're correct. your solution is much more elegant. I would make this a two step solution. One to query the drop down two to write a formula down the adjacent column with text joins so each record appears on a new line.