# attempting to compile an output List, into a single cell in one Sheet, based on matching criteria in a range on another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I found a proposed solution on Stack, but I can't get it to work.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/120111/270308

Starting formula:

```
=IF(G3<>""; JOIN(CHAR(10); FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!B1:B &" "&
                                               Sheet1!C1:C &" "&
                                               Sheet1!D1:D); Sheet1!A1:A=G3));)
```

I modified to match my Sheet's info, but I can't get to work.

I'm getting Filter range size errors:

 --FILTER has mismatched range sizes.

 --Expected row count: 1000. column count: 1.

 --Actual row count: 1. column count: 1.

What I have noticed:

- my formula refuses to maintain the ";" and autochanges them to ","
- I have the added AND(), rather than a simple "="

My formula:

```
=IF(B4<>"",
JOIN(CHAR(10), FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA('Drive-Times'!A$3:A &"-"&
                                    'Drive-Times'!B$3:B), 
                                AND('Drive-Times'!D$3:D>=B4,'Drive-Times'!D$3:D<B5))),)
```

my [sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xDmi33oPiMN1YhCTUfCig22pT7UCF1PJDNi8pEy8wb0/edit?usp=sharing)

My problem cell is highlighted in Green:  compilations!A4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup of the formula is incorrect. `FILTER` can take any number of comma-separated arguments; it doesn't need the `AND` grouping. In addition, `AND` does not work within `ArrayFormula` anyway (and you didn't need `ArrayFormula` here, because `FILTER` is its own built-in array formula.

Try this:

`=IF(B4<>"", JOIN(CHAR(10), FILTER('Drive-Times'!A$3:A & "-" & 'Drive-Times'!B$3:B, 'Drive-Times'!C$3:C>=B4, 'Drive-Times'!C$3:C<B5)),)`

The use of semicolons in your template formula means that this person has a sheet that is set to a locale that uses semicolons in place of commas. Your sheet locale uses commas.

**ADDENDUM (w/ IFERROR)**

`=IF(B4<>"", IFERROR(JOIN(CHAR(10), FILTER('Drive-Times'!A$3:A & "-" & 'Drive-Times'!B$3:B, 'Drive-Times'!C$3:C>=B4, 'Drive-Times'!C$3:C<B5)),"NONE"),)`

Comment: It works great on my original as well!  Thank you! Is there a way to mod it to return something else if no matches are found (eg. a blank "", or "NONE", or "n/a"?

Comment: See ADDENDUM to my post. If you would, please take a moment to complete the circle by marking that post "Best Answer." This indicates to contributors at a glance which issues have been fully resolved, as well as helping future site visitors like yourself most quickly find the answers to their own similar questions.

Comment: Sorry, imma noob. I clicked to Accept the answer, but I don't see "Best Answer" anywhere.

Comment: You must have figured it out, because it is showing now. Thanks.